# NodeJS: How can I print a "left arrow" character?

Tags: javascript, node.js, char, hex

I have the hex representation of the "left arrow" key as "1b5b44" (I got it from, basically,

```
stdin.on("data", function (chunk) {
  console.log("hex:", chunk.toString("hex");
})
```

Then in the terminal just pressed the arrow key.  It works fine for checking if the incoming chunk is a left arrow press, but how can I go the other way?  Given the hex code, how can I write the character?

```
process.stdout.write( ??? );
```

Comment: Are you looking for a graphical depiction of an arrow, or do you want the escape sequences to move the cursor?

Comment: @icktoofay the escape sequences to move the cursor.  Preferrably a list of such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

### Theory

Cursor movement is controlled using the escape character, followed by a sequence of code that, when combined, the terminal prints as a movement of the cursor.

### Example

Here is some example code that does what we want:

```
// Create a string that will move the cursor.  The arg "num" is the number
// of columns to move
function cursor_left (num) {
  num = num || ""   // empty string implies the number 1
  var esc = "\033"; // The "escape" char represented as an octal string.
  return esc + "[" + num + "D";
}

prefix  = "ABC";
suffix  = "XYZ";
```

And in the repl:

```
> console.log(prefix + cursor_left() + suffix);
ABXYZ
> console.log(prefix + cursor_left(2) + "X");
AXC
```

In the context of a terminal in "raw" mode, this has the effect of "printing" arrow movements.

### Existing Package

There's a nodejs package, [terminal](https://github.com/mattijs/node-terminal), that has done the lifting for you if you're wanting to move around the terminal.  I haven't tested the package itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Given the hex code, how can I write the character?

There is no such thing as a character representing the left arrow key.

The shell you are using for stdin to your process interprets a left arrow key press as three characters: `<ESC>[D`.

If you output those three characters, it is meaningless to your shell unless you evaluate them, just like outputting `echo foobar` or `$?`, doesn't mean anything special unless you tell a shell to execute it.

> It works fine for checking if the incoming chunk is a left arrow press

You can't distinguish a left arrow press from an `<ESC>` character followed by the two characters `[D`; that's the specific character sequence you are recognizing, whether it came from pressing the left arrow key or not (EG. it could've come from `echo "\033[D" | node main.js`)

Comment: Well, respectfully, I disagree.  Because I'm listening to stdin in "raw" mode, I'm reading data keypress by keypress.  While the left arrow is equivalent to <ESC>[D, I can distinguish between them because the actual key presses come in distinguished.  That said, my main question still stands:  How can I get the cursor to move leftward one column without pressing a left arrow?  *something* is being sent to the terminal when I press the left arrow and then process.stdout.write(chunk).  How do I represent whatever that is in code?